# Hide html DOM data to end user

Tags: javascript, html

http://callmenick.com/_development/memory/ Without inspect element I can know the hidden image by looking at the DOM. Says I want to make competition using this game, how can that be done? How to make the game non-hackable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot truly make it "unhackable" unless you store the contents of the game in another location, like on some server. You can make it *more difficult* for people to figure out the data (obfuscation), but if your JS can understand the data, and the JS is loaded in the browser, then all the information is there for reverse engineering by someone that is dedicated to the task.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use base64 instead of an image path. This would at least make it much more difficult for someone to see what image is what. Instead of a friendly file path, it'd be a long string of characters.

Another good option would be to look at some of the options mentioned in the article below:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/article.php/3875651/Web-Developer-Class-How-to-Hide-your-Source-Code.htm

Comment: base64 make sense! thanks! normal user would not be able to guess it here

Comment: Not sure how base64 would help this question. If someone wanted to "hack" the game I'm sure they would know how to reverse a simple base64 string also once the image had rendered in the browser it's pretty hard to cover up a way of copying/accessing the real image. Obviously the real path can be hidden but yet pointless as you still need to give the client access otherwise the image will never render. .htaccess or server side would do both but hiding the image source isn't going to help.